# In Typescript, how do I convert a string of strings as an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, string, typescript, angular11

Probably similar to other questions. My example string looks like this:
"['one', 'two', 'three']"
Can I do it without resorting to Regex or so?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example string is *almost* valid JSON, so smth like [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=19#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOBlKAnASzAHMYBeGAIgG0BycOWgGhlqgHcRnWoALPOIwC6lAHQRMBKAApaAHVq0AlKIBWIIrMrKA3AChQkWEjx4kAT3IwAUtgDyAOVFoTEONMSpMOfEWJKYJAgYaEISaiF9QwgQLFEMEGJpEzNzJSA)